# Filter Method Behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, filter, ternary

## Why filter method can't work with ternary conditional as it works with if conditionals ?

**In case it works with `if..else`**

```
let numbers = [-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3];
let negatives = [];

let positives = numbers.filter(num => {
   if(num > 0) {
     return num;                      // positives array => [1, 2, 3]
   } else {
     negatives.push(num);             // negatives array => [-1, -2, -3]
   }
})
```

**In case it works with `?`**

```
let positives = numbers.filter(num => num > 0 ? num : negatives.push(num));

// positives array => [-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3]

// negatives array => [-1, -2, -3]
```

I tried filter method with if conditionals and it returns the result as I expect. but what is not expected for me the result when it works with ternary conditional.

Comment: `filter` returns either the item or not. a different value than the item's value is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are misunderstanding what the code you pasted does.

Let's see.. in the first code, the fitering function returns either `num` or nothing (after `negatives.push()` there is no `return`, so it implicitly returns `undefined`).

```js
function fn(){ 
  // no explicit return
}
const what = fn();
typeof what === "undefined"; // true
```

The second version, returns either `num` or **the returned value of `negatives.push()` call**, which is [by definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

> ##### Return value
>
> The new length property of the object upon which the method was called.

So in the second version of the code, the `filter` receives for every *negative* number: 0, 1, 2... and so on. The first occurrence will be taken as a "falsy" ([0 is a "falsy" value in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)) so it will be filtered out from the resulting array, the following negative numbers will be included in the resulting array as the filtering function will return "truthy" values for them ([positive numbers are "truthy" values in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy))

---

#### Being that said...

It is a bad practice to use a `filter` function for other task than filtering things.
In this scenario where you need to separate positives from negatives, use `forEach` which is more clear and appropriate.

```js
const positives = [];
const negatives = [];

numbers.forEach(num => {
   if(num > 0) { // Note: that this comparison will send ZEROES to negatives array, which could lead to a bug.
     positives.push(num);
   } else {
     negatives.push(num);
   }
});
```

or simpler:

```js
const positives = [];
const negatives = [];

numbers.forEach(num => (num > 0 ? positives : negatives).push(num));
```

Answer (score 0):

The array method `filter` expects a callback which returns a boolean value. In your second example you are returning `num` when `num` is positive (which is truthy).

However, when `num` is negative, the method returns the result of `negatives.push(num)` which is also truthy.